# DicomToMesh OSX Building Issue

Tags: c++, cmake, qt5, mesh, dcom

I want to compile DicomToMesh according to the instructions [in this link](https://github.com/AOT-AG/DicomToMesh).

```
> git clone https://github.com/AOT-AG/DicomToMesh.git
> cd DicomToMesh
> mkdir build
> cd build
> ccmake ..  #opens ccmake window
```

By executing above instruction I supposed to get something similar to the following within the ccmake window,

```
BUILD_GUI                        OFF
CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE                 DEBUG
CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX             /usr/local                                   
USE_VTK_DICOM                    OFF                                          
VTK_DIR                          /home/eidelen/Development/libs/vtk/build
```

But in my case I'm getting this result:
[image: my results]

After pressing `c`, it generates following error:

```
CMake Error at /usr/local/lib/cmake/vtk-9.0/VTK-vtk-module-find-packages.cmake:115
 (find_package):
   By not providing "FindQt5.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
   asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5", but
   CMake did not find one.

   Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5" (requested
   version 5.15) with any of the following names:

     Qt5Config.cmake
     qt5-config.cmake

   Add the installation prefix of "Qt5" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set "Qt5_DIR"
   to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "Qt5" provides a
   separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been installed.
 Call Stack (most recent call first):
   /usr/local/lib/cmake/vtk-9.0/vtk-config.cmake:131 (include)
   CMakeLists.txt:5 (find_package)

 Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
 See also "/Users/mrhs/DicomToMesh/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
 See also "/Users/mrhs/DicomToMesh/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

I have installed QT5 5.15.2 using

> brew install qt5

I tried to follow [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47647035/cmake-prefix-path-doesnt-help-cmake-in-finding-qt5) using command

```
brew install qtbase5-dev
brew install qtdeclarative5-dev
```

But getting `Warning: No available formula or cask with the name "qtbase5-dev".` and `Error: No similarly named formulae found'`

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18722329/cmake-does-not-find-qt-5-1-1) solution by using the command

```
export CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/qt@5/
cd build
```

but it is showing `No such file or directory`

I'm using this for the first time and my be i'm missing something which I could not figure out yet. I will be really very thankful and will appreciate it if anyone can help me. I badly need to solve this issue and has spend a lot of time but in vain.

N.B. This is my [CMakeError.log](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MBiU0Gne5ZpwMETOn-Uy1t9qzT7jDfUE/view?usp=sharing) and [CMakeOutput.log](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1T1_Gl-Z5Pl2HcY7oCkgdDldu73Ks4VwP/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Hi, Im the author of Dicom2Mesh. Qt is only required when you build the GUI (BUILD_GUI=ON). For the command line application you don't need it. Further on I saw that you use VTK 9. Unfortunately that does not work, however there is a special branch for that: vtk-9-novisual

Answer (score 0):

Installing `brew install qt5`, at the end the process is going to display something like :

```sh
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/qt@5/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/qt@5/lib" 
export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/qt@5/include"
```

Just type them in your terminal

Comment: I applied your solution but I'm still having the same Error "Could not find a package configuration file provided by Qt5" after the compilation but qt5 is already installed. I have executed your solution both inside the build folder and out side of it. I don't know what's the missing point.

Comment: @Suvro can you reinstall qt with `brew reinstall qt@5` ? At the end you'll see the commands. Maybe the paths will be slightly different on your computer